# MissingRequestHeaderException on production but not on local

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, request-headers

I'm getting the next exeption when I call GET controller in production, in local works fine:

`Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'user_id' for method parameter type String is not present]`

If I try using postman I got 400 Bad Request, in local works fine.

Here is my controler

```
    @GetMapping(path ="/get")
    public ResponseEntity <UserDto> getUserInformationById(@RequestHeader("user_id") final String id){
        UserDto userDto = userInformationService.getUserInformationById(id);
        if (userDto==null)
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto);
    }
```

Why is failing on production but not in local? another similar endpoints of the same class work fine, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by removing the underscore from the headers, I used `userId`

instead, and it worked.

[Here](https://www.grouparoo.com/blog/dont-use-underscores-in-http-headers) you can read more about it